# Create custom parameter to Grails application's configuration

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDEA and Grails as my application framework. 
My application is mainly on Groovy.

I am trying to add external custom argument as an external parameter to my application.

I have opened the Edit Configurations... and tried different ways to add custom arguments in the **VM options**, and inside the **Program Arguments**, but with no success.

Here is an example to one try I did:

I added

```
-Dcustom.arg=100
```

to the VM options.

I would like to know if it is possible to inject external variable by using the Application configuration?If yes, how should it be done?

Comment: Please show your Groovy code that confirms the VM Options not working.

Comment: There is no groovy code confirmation that the VM options is not working. The application is up and running but I did not get the arg key with the value 100.

Comment: What code do you use to know that it didn't get the JVM option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be done by adding a new program argument to the **Edit configuration --> Program Arguments**:

Just add a new value of the custom argument such as: **externalArg**.

And in the application code, find the section read those properties.

For example:

```
Properties props = System.properties
String propValue = props.get("sun.java.command").toString()
```

the propValue contains all the Program Arguments and specifically the  **externalArg** parameter you have inserted.

Another option can be done by inserting the variable into the **Edit configuration --> VM Options**. When using grails, the parameter should look like that:

```
-Dgrails.externalVariable=3
```

Reading the externalVariable inside the application is done by:

```
Object externalVariable = System.getProperties().get("grails.externalVariable")
```

**Note**:
Both of those 2 options give the same result. 
Using each one of the options should be related to the variable concept.
If you wish to have the **externalVariable** as a program argument insert the parameter into the **Program Arguments**.
If you wish to have the **externalVariable** as a Virtual machine parameter insert the parameter into the **VM Options**.